# FabricJS - Setting object position with pivot being top-left corner

Tags: canvas, positioning, conventions, fabricjs

I started using the quite awesome [FabricJS](http://fabricjs.com) framework, and noticed that object positioning works a bit different from CSS conventions. Where CSS places the positioning pivot on the top-left corner, FabricJS has it placed at the center of the object:

## CSS

```
@------------
|           |
|           |
|           |
|           |
|           |
-------------
```

## FabricJS

```
-------------
|           |
|           |
|     @     |
|           |
|           |
-------------
```

Is there a way to control this setting? thanks.

---

### EDIT:

This is an exiting item on the [roadmap](https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/wiki/Roadmap,-TODO) for the project. So it'll happen in the future, but is currently not supported.

Answer (score 5):

You can now specify the "origin" of the positioning of the object when you create it.

**originX** defaults to "center", but you can change it to "left" or "right"

**originY** defaults to "center" but you can change it to "bottom" or "top"

It's specified in the [docs](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Object.html).
And here is a [test](http://fabricjs.com/test/misc/origin.html).